# OOP class AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute 'print_mana'

Tags: python, class, oop, attributeerror

I'm quiet new to OOP in python, and I want to create a class that inherit other class methods, here is my code:

```
class setting_mana:
  def __init__(self,mana=30):
    self.print_mana = mana


class Player(setting_mana):
    def __init__(self, hit_points, sides):
        self.hit_points = hit_points
        self.sides = sides

    def take_hit(self):
        self.hit_points -= 2
        return self.hit_points

alexandre = Player(10,6)

alexandre.print_mana()
```

I want to inherit `print_mana` from the class `setting_mana`. How should I do it so the error: `AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute 'print_mana'` does not appear?

Comment: Since the `Player` class has its own definition of `__init__`, it does _not_ inherit the one from the parent class.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `super()`, call's the parent's `__init__` function, allowing your Player class to have the `print_mana` attribute as well.

```
class setting_mana:
  def __init__(self,mana=30):
    self.print_mana = mana


class Player(setting_mana):
    def __init__(self, hit_points, sides):
        super().__init__() # Add this
        self.hit_points = hit_points
        self.sides = sides

    def take_hit(self):
        self.hit_points -= 2
        return self.hit_points

alexandre = Player(10,6)

print(alexandre.print_mana)
```

Output:

```
30
```

Comment: All calling `super().__init__()` does is execute the parent class' `__init__()` method — **not** make the subclass  inherit all of the properties of the parent.

Comment: How do I make the subclass inherit all of the properties of the parent? Or even specific classes?

Comment: According to the testing I just did, any functions you add to `setting_mana` will be accessible through the player class, as long as you have the `super()` line

Comment: @Alexandre: You are confusing class methods and instance attributes (which is what they're called in Python, not "properties" which are something else).  Methods are inherited automatically when you define the bases of a class in its `class` statement. Class instance attributes are usually created in a class' `__init__()` method — so if you want the same ones that the base creates you can call *its* `__init__()` method via `super()` as illustrated in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

1. You are attempting to use the attribute `print_mana` as a method when it's really an integer by the looks of it.
2. `print_mana` (the attribute which I renamed to `mana` below) is not defined on instances of `Player` because you need to call the parent class constructor

I think what you want is something like this?

```
class ManaMixin:
    def __init__(self, mana=30):
        self.mana = mana

    def print_mana(self):
        print(self.mana)


class Player(ManaMixin):
    def __init__(self, hit_points, sides):
        super().__init__()
        self.hit_points = hit_points
        self.sides = sides

    def take_hit(self):
        self.hit_points -= 2
        return self.hit_points


p = Player(10, 6)
p.print_mana()  # prints 30
```